# WCF (4.0) how to exclude nonce tag

Tags: wcf, jboss

We’ve written a WCF (4.0) client of a web service for which the WSDL includes the following security policy

```
<wsp:UsingPolicy wssutil:Required="true"/>
    <wsp:Policy wssutil:Id="UsernameTokenPolicy">
        <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:UsernameToken>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SupportingTokens>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

The headers in our messages include the `<nonce>` tag. We didn’t have to explicitly write code to do this – it appears the .NET libraries automatically generate a nonce value and add it.

The problem is the server we’re talking to has been changed. It is now a JBOSS server (was previously WebLogic) and, apparently, whoever has deployed it is saying that it’s rejecting our messages because of the `<nonce>` tag.

From what I can see JBOSS does properly handle the `<nonce>` tag, so I’m not sure why it’s being rejected – I assume it’s a configuration setting on their end. **[Edit] JBOSS strictly follows the WSSE uername and Token Security Spec 1,1, which requires that the Nonce explicitly provide and EncodingType. The .NET Framework does not strictly follow this spec.**

However, I’d like to know is there any way of configuring my WCF client to not include the `<nonce>` tag?

I’d prefer not to have code the header explicitly as that would require rolling out patches with proper testing, etc. and would also be more prone to error. So, I’m really hoping there’s a client configuration option for this.